# BASH: curl get url based on datestring

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have a problem with curl and I would like to know if is possible to develop a thing I have on mind:

When I do the curl request I obtain the following xml structure and basically i want to filter first by dates and then obtain urls with dates in 2023-07

```
<log>https://www.url1.com</log>
<date>2023-07-10T04:22:07Z</date>
<log>https://www.url2.com</log>
<date>2023-07-12T04:22:07Z</date>
<log>https://www.url3.com</log>
<date>2023-04-03T04:22:07Z</date>
```

I was trying to use grep and awk to extract first the dates and then the urls but I'm stuck trying how can i achieve that:
at the moment i just have this command:

`curl -s https://url.com | grep -E 'https://\[^ \>\]+'`

So if is possible to filter the xml first to obtain just urls with dates in 2023-07? Like this:

```
<log>https://www.url1.com</log>
<date>2023-07-10T04:22:07Z</date>
<log>https://www.url2.com</log>
<date>2023-07-12T04:22:07Z</date>
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with `curl`. The filtering you're doing does not depend on where the text came from.

Comment: `grep -B 1 '<date>2023-07-'` will return the dates you want with 1 line before each.

Comment: @Barmar yes xml. sorry I typed wrong the data

Comment: You should use an XML-parser for this.